# Why we can't say "'this black guy" in Europe

Tags: spoken-english

To day, I read on News by Vietnamese. I known that Paris Saint-Germain's vs Istanbul Basaksehir Game suspended after alleged racist abuse by official.

So, he just Said: "this black guy"?

In Asia football, I see, a lot of people can said it.

For example in V-League, the is a lot of player from Africa but we can say:

"Anh da đen đó đá hay quá." It same "This black guy play very well". But any one happy, no problem.

But I don't know why we can't said this in Europe? Hope any one can explain for me, and the best way we can say in this situation?

Sorry that my English writing is not good. Hope some one help edit.

Comment: What was the exact sentence said? I think you have to be pretty careful about mentioning someone's race or colour in a context where it's irrelevant. If you are frustrated with someone and you add in an irrelevant mention that they are "black", it comes across as abusive.

Comment: You can see at: https://sports.ndtv.com/football/champions-league-psg-vs-istanbul-basaksehir-game-suspended-after-alleged-racist-abuse-by-official-2336071

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the referee was speaking Romanian, so it's not really a question about English. But the issue certainly applies to English as spoken in Western Europe (not only by native speakers).

It's a political question to an extent, and to that extent it will generate heated politicial discussion, inappropriate here. But to give you a purely linguistic and hopefully ideologically neutral answer, the term 'black guy' used in English, in a Western European context, in public life, is no longer felt to be appropriate.

The Romanian term used was 'negru' (which just means 'black', as seen in the delicious wines of Moldova like Negru de Purcari), and in Eastern Europe the equivalent terms are more used in everyday life and not felt to be offensive by the majority of the population. In Western Europe, terms that overtly refer to skin colour are now seen as offensive by many.

Note that with the Vietnamese you are saying 'anh da đen', and the use of the word 'anh' automatically confers a level of respect (not a high level, but some level nonetheless) which 'guy' does not in English. If you said 'thằng da đen' instead, this might be a bit closer to the effect of what was said on the pitch.